# How to add a text box with a magnifier icon at the corner in windows forms using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to add a textbox with a magnifier icon at the corner..Please suggest me ways of doing so using C# code and also ensure that text does not get hidden under the magnifier symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is UserControl .

> A UserControl is a customized control that consists of other standard
>   controls.

To make one:

1.Start a new WindowsFormsControlLibrary project

2.In UserControl1 add controls and change their properties as you like (ie. TextBox, Button, etc.)

3.Compile the project

4.Drag the DLL file from Bin folder to your ToolBox

5.Use your UserControl1 like other controls

May be this link can be useful to you :-

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Controls/ListBox_and_ComboBox/TextBox_Icon/article.asp